# Keep browser extension popup open when a authentication child window is closed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser

My Chrome extension's popup opens a new window via window.open(), when I am clicking on button (Sign In) present in popup screen for authentication, after authentication done that child window closed, but it closes the extension's popup itself. Here extension popup disappears quickly before the user notices the message after authentication done.

This is how the window is opened

```
window.open(url, target, windowFeatures)
```

Is this because of the focus shifting between windows? What can I do for popup window to stay on while longer so the user notices the message ?

Comment: Create a new tab with popup and it will create a window for authentication.

Comment: Authentication window is opening by clicking on a button(Sign in) which is present in popup, It is already a new tab opens left top. The issue is only when authentication window get closed, it closes extension popup also.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new tab with popup and it will create a window for authentication.

popup.html

```html
<html>
  <body>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
chrome.tabs.create({ url: "auth.html" });
```

auth.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <button id="auth">auth</button>
  <script src="auth.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

auth.js

```js
document.getElementById("auth").onclick = () => {
  auth();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you run this code in the popup, it opens a new tab in the background and keeps the popup open:

```
chrome.tabs.create({ active: false, url: "https://stackoverflow.com/" });
```

When you close the new tab by calling [chrome.tabs.remove](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-remove) in the popup, the popup also stays open.

There is also [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/windows/#method-create), but it always closes the popup, even when you call it with `focused: false` and/or `state: "minimized"`

Tested in Chromium 108.0.5359.124 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-Bit))

Proof of concept:

`manifest.json`

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Open new Tab from Popup",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

`popup.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Open new Tab from Popup</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Open new Tab from Popup</h1>
        <button id="create_tab">Create Tab</button>
        <button id="close_tab">Close Tab</button>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

`popup.js`

```
let tab_id = null;

async function create_tab(event) {
    if (tab_id === null) {
        let tab = await chrome.tabs.create({ active: false, url: "https://stackoverflow.com/" });
        tab_id = tab.id;
    }
    else {
        console.log("There is already an open tab.");
    }
}

function close_tab(event) {
    if (tab_id === null) {
        console.log("There is no open tab.");
    }
    else {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab_id);
        tab_id = null;
    }
}

document.getElementById("create_tab").addEventListener("click", create_tab);
document.getElementById("close_tab").addEventListener("click", close_tab);
```

Note:
When you close the popup, the extension forgets the ID of the new tab.
So the following sequence of events creates a tab that you need to close manually:

1. Open the popup
2. Click the "Create Tab" button
3. Close the popup
4. Open the popup again
5. Click the "Close Tab" button